# Get specific properties from an object

Tags: c#

I am filling up an object which has a lot of properties, and then I simply print them. the **filling up** process is done inside a library which means I cant control it.

```
var response = await _api.Campaigns.UpdateAsync(campaignId, campaign);  
return Ok(response);
```

This `response` is of type `Campaign`. Among all of its properties there is one called `Links`. What I want to do is, I want to remove that `Link` property from `response` and then return `response`. But I just found that removing a property from an object is not possible (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I thought maybe I could just copy the required properties into a new object using foreach loop and then ultimately return it. So I tried this,

```
var response = await _api.Campaigns.UpdateAsync(campaignId, campaign);
var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (PropertyInfo info in response.GetType().GetProperties())
    result.Add(info.Name, info.GetMethod);
return Ok(result);
```

I am no expert on this kinda things but of course this provides only the names of the properties and their information. So it's output looks like this,

```
"ArchiveUrl": {
    "Name": "get_ArchiveUrl",
    "AssemblyName": "***",
    "ClassName": "MailChimp.Net.Models.Campaign",
    "Signature": "System.String get_ArchiveUrl()",
    "Signature2": "System.String get_ArchiveUrl()",
    "MemberType": 8,
    "GenericArguments": null
},
"LongArchiveUrl": {
    "Name": "get_LongArchiveUrl",
    "AssemblyName": "***",
    "ClassName": "MailChimp.Net.Models.Campaign",
    "Signature": "System.String get_LongArchiveUrl()",
    "Signature2": "System.String get_LongArchiveUrl()",
    "MemberType": 8,
    "GenericArguments": null
},
"ContentType": {
    "Name": "get_ContentType",
    "AssemblyName": "***",
    "ClassName": "MailChimp.Net.Models.Campaign",
    "Signature": "System.String get_ContentType()",
    "Signature2": "System.String get_ContentType()",
    "MemberType": 8,
    "GenericArguments": null
},
```

But the output should be like this,

```
"archive_url": "***",
"long_archive_url": "***",
"content_type": "template",
"create_time": "2018-06-28T15:30:50+06:00",
"delivery_status": {
    "enabled": false,
    "can_cancel": false,
    "status": null,
    "emails_sent": 0,
    "emails_canceled": 0
},
"rss_opts": null,
"social_card": {
    "image_url": "*|BRAND:LOGO|*",
    "description": "",
    "title": ""
},
```

So what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Why can't you just return `response` instead of using all that reflection code?

Comment: If I return `response` then it also includes `Links` property which I dont want. I also thought about creating a duplicate class of `Campaign` with only those properties that I want and then copy `response` to that, but there are a lot of functions that does this kinda operations. So I am trying to avoid that technique and trying to find a better and simpler technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your output is that you are returning `info.GetMethod` instead of `info.Value(response)`. However, I would suggest using a different method for only returning certain properties. Create your new class with the properties you need and return that instead. For example:

```
public class SimpleCampaign
{
    public string ArchiveUrl { set; set; }
    public string LongArchiveUrl { get; set; }
    //etc. choosing only the properties you need
}
```

And then:

```
var simpleResponse = new SimpleCampaign
{
    ArchiveUrl = response.ArchiveUrl,
    LongArchiveUrl = response.LongArchiveUrl,
    //etc.
}

return Ok(simpleResponse);
```

Of course, writing code to map from one object to another is a pain in the backside. But there are libraries out there to help. I suggest using [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org), it's a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) that is very easy to use and will do all your mapping automagically.

Answer (score 1):

I think [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in response.GetType().GetProperties())
    result.Add(info.Name, info.GetValue(response));
```

PS: If you only want to get Public Properties

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in response.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public))
    result.Add(info.Name, info.GetValue(response));
```